# How to analyze assembly code for stack frames?

Tags: assembly

I have the following code:

```
Func5() { ShowStackTrace();}
Func4() { Func5();}
```

Here is the stack trace I have -

```
**Frame for Func5**
EIP : 403899
Function name : Func5
EBP : 12ff0c
ESP : 12fed0
Return address : 4038c8
CS : 23
DS : 9998
ESI : 0
EDI : 0

**Frame for Func4**
Function name : Func4
EBP : 12ff14
ESP : 12ff14
CS : 23
DS : 9998
ESI : 0
EDI : 0
```

Now using the return address of Func5 I got the first 5 bytes above it

```
ff ff ff 88 E8
```

The presence of E8 here means this is a call statement (near) and the next 4 bytes are to be used to calculate the address. So the EIP when we read CALL Func5 will be 4038c3. How do I calculate the starting address of Func5 from this data?
Please do tell if you need any other data. Also how is the calculation done if this is a far call (opcode - FF)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the bytes in inverse order. The correct order is:

```
E8 88 ff ff ff
```

where `E8` is opcode for "jump relative imm32"

That would mean `jump relative 0xFFFFFF88`, or `-0x78` because x86 uses little endiannes.

EDIT: it's relative to the next byte after the call instruction. Eg,

```
0x100: E8 10 00 00 00 ;// call relative, will call 0x115 (0x105 + 0x10)
                      ;// and will leave 0x105 on the stack as return address
0x105: 90             ;// next instruction
```

Comment: You are of course right. How do I get the final address? It is relative to what? CS?

Comment: So here it will be 0x403850. Cool. Thanks a lot. How do we calculate it for FAR CALL (opcode - FF)? I feel like giving you all my points right now!

Comment: @Bruce: There is no "far" call in 32 bit assembly. Probably you are asking about `0xFF15` and `0xFF25` opcodes, that represents `jump [imm32]` and `call [imm32]`.

Comment: There are plenty of them :) Maximum opcode lenght for x86 is 17 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the plateform. On most UNICES the dladdr provides the nearest symbol to an address.

On windows it is more complicated : look at dbghelp.dll and msapi.dll APIs.
I do not remember excatly but this is not far.